# Defining Array by maintaining Order with different types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an array that has different types - String, Number, and Boolean. I want to make sure the elements are present in that order. The array is like below:

```
const idList : (String| Number | Boolean )[] = ["someStringId1","someStringId2", 01, 09, true, false];
```

I used the Type annotation already to accept any String or Number or Boolean.

How to make sure it accepts only String, Number and Boolean in that order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) which is treated as a very limited array accepting *only* a certain number of items and *only* of certain types for each position:

```js
type MyTuple = [string, number, boolean];

const correctTuple: MyTuple = ["hello", 42, true];

const incorrectTuple1: MyTuple = ["hello", "42", "true"];
const incorrectTuple2: MyTuple = ["hello", 42, true, "world"];
const incorrectTuple3: MyTuple = ["hello", 42];
```

[Try it in the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAqBXMAbaBeKBtAzsATgJYB2A5gDRTGIC2ARhPpXQPYtoCGxAugNwBQ-AMYtieKCPz4IQ4ElQQAXLATI0UTFgBEACwgoULLZQAsAJkoFEEPoJFjgUEpOmz5aAIzK47jNl36hsZQWubBWlYQWrb24s4sUjJyahBm3qoKGv56BkamFlCRlFoA7gkoACbRArGO8YluKQDM6b5Z2jlB+XxAA)